# Is there a systematic procedure to do data cleaning or preprocessing?

Tags: data-transformation, data-preprocessing

I do data cleaning / data preprocessing everyday, using various tools to remove outliers and to keep normality

However, I feel what I am doing is more a handcraft rather than systematic: I don't have a procedure to guild me what should I do or more importantly: why should I do this?

I am now looking for a more 'systematic' approach of data preprocessing: can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you by now find enough information to answer the question yourself? It is yet a relevant question.